How to pass secret via dockerfile mount?
I am unable to run dockerbuild to mount a secret to pass to the container.
This is an example public repo to show the problem in github:
https://github.com/inspiraller/docker-node-get-secrets
Dockerfile
FROM node:20
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY node-files .
RUN npm ci && npm run build
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=THEPASSWORD1   #,target=./run/secrets/THEPASSWORD1
CMD ["node", "dist/get-secrets.js"]

I tried to follow the guidelines on the main docker website: https://docs.docker.com/build/building/secrets/
The intention is to pass my local file ./.secrets/THEPASSWORD1 (which contains the value) to /run/secrets/THEPASSWORD1

docker build -t distroless-node-dumbinit:1 --secret id=THEPASSWORD1,src=./.secrets/THEPASSWORD1 --secret id=THEPASSWORD2,src=./.secrets/THEPASSWORD2 --no-cache .

When I run this container:
docker run --name distroless-node-dumbinit distroless-node-dumbinit:1
It doesn't work
Though when I use docker-compose.yml, using a different approach it does work.
I am expecting the console.log the value of THEPASSWORD1 in my get-secrets.js node file. It is expecting to get the secret from /run/secrets/THEPASSWORD1

It sounds like you're hoping docker run --rm your-image cat /run/secrets/THEPASSWORD1 will retrieve the secret in plain text?  You typically want to avoid embedding the actual secret into the image, since anyone who gets a copy of the image would be able to run the same command.  RUN --mount=... doesn't persist the mounted content beyond the immediate RUN directive.

@DavidMaze Thanks for your reply. What about the docker-compose which puts this into that location?

That's probably fine.  The important detail here is that you don't need the secret at build time, since you don't want to build it into the image (and expose it).  That means you need the secret when you run the container instead.

@DavidMaze I understand, but not sure why the solution exists as suggested by the docker guideline link above. I interpreted that run bind mount to mount the value into the image when run. I probably am missing something then, in my docker run statement. Just not sure what. Maybe I have to supply a volume.

There are several usecases for mounting secrets for a run command to build an image such as fetch external artifacts from a secure source. If you add a private npm registry, you could mount your .npmrc as a secret in the RUN --mount command to install packages.

@DavidMaze, I am facing OP's issue exactly who follows the Docker's own building secrets docs. Can you advise how to persist the secret in a running container with only Dockefile (and not docker compose)?

@Parfait - see my working example below

@Parfait you don't. The RUN --mount-type=secret syntax is for build time secrets and mount the secret for the duration of the RUN command only. compose secrets are the only explicit support docker has for runtime secret mounting outside of docker swarm mode.

For anyone else with this problem. Here is a working example with passing secrets into an image single line. Note. You woudn't don't this normally, but this is just to show it working.
Dockerfile
FROM debian:stable-slim
COPY private-install-script.sh .

# For the next 2 commands comment one or the other out to prove that ACCESS_TOKEN will only be available to the first comnand

# 1. Doing RUN here of private-install-script.sh is going to output that token back to a file /tmp/dontdothis
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=ACCESS_TOKEN ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/ACCESS_TOKEN) ./private-install-script.sh

# 2. Doing RUN here will NOT pass ACCESS_TOKEN. This is just an example to prove it won't pass it in. 
# RUN ./private-install-script.sh
# -----------------
# Now display the contents of /tmp/dontdothis
CMD ["cat", "/tmp/dontdothis"]

private-install-script.sh
#!/bin/sh

# ON BUILD
echo "ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN=${ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN}. cat run/secrets/ACCESS_TOKEN=$(cat /run/secrets/ACCESS_TOKEN)" > /tmp/dontdothis

Create secret via terminal
export ACCESS_TOKEN=mysupersecret123
Create the build (will use the above created secret)
docker build --secret "id=ACCESS_TOKEN" -t build-secret:1 .
Run the build
docker run --name build-secret build-secret:1

mysupersecret123

To prove the secret is not acessible via the build

docker image history build-secret:1 --no-trunc

